# rename file name with eloquent way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
File.rename(blog_path + '/' + project_path, File.expand_path(topic_name, blog_path))
```

I use these code to rename ruby file name, but I think there is a better way to write this functionality with less code since it includes blog_path two times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is OK, but I think there is no need to `expand_path` here - this method creates an absolute path from the the relative one.

Also, it is good to use `File.join` to create a path instead just concatenate it with slash - it will be completely OS independent. So I would write your code like this:

```
File.rename(File.join(blog_path, project_path), File.join(blog_path, topic_name))
```

Or if you want to get rid of doubled `blog_path`, change working directory before doing a rename:

```
Dir.chdir(blog_path)
File.rename(project_path, topic_name)
```

More info on working with files and directories in Ruby you can find in the article: [Ruby for Admins: Files and Directories](http://rubyforadmins.com/files-and-directories).